# Euclidean divison program

Tags: number-theory

I learnt that, given two integers $a$ and $b$, with $b \neq 0$, there exist unique integers $q$ and $r$ such that $a = bq + r$ and $0 \leq r < |b|$, where $|b|$ denotes the absolute value of $b$ - Definition.

The below program is performing euclidean division:

```
 -((-n - 1) / d) - 1     if n < 0 and d > 0

 n/d                     if n > 0 and d > 0

 where / is real division of math.
```

So, my question is: 
What is the idea behind this non-obvious formulae, when $n < 0$ & $d > 0$?

Please help me!!!

---

```
int ifloordiv(int n, int d){

if (n >= 0)
    return n / d;
else
    return ~(~n / d);
}
```

---

Comment: I repeat, Emphasis is on understanding the approach to think of using bit complement operator.

Comment: above program is in java and java does not support euclidean divison

Comment: so what i see is in the above code,                                               if i need to perform euclidean divison of -3/4, then -3/4 -> 2/4 using ~(bitwise 1's complement) and then real divison  2/4 is performed which gives 0 and then bitwise 1's complement of 0 gives -1, How can one think of this flow to write the logic?

Comment: java only supports real divison by default not euclidean divison

Comment: I think you have to figure out (or find written down somewhere) the mathematical relation between a number and its bit complement.

Comment: @GerryMyerson i wrote the mathematical relation between a number and its complement in question directly, so ~n is (-n -1), Do you think you can help me now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easiest to see what's going on if we look at an example.

Suppose we want to divide one of the numbers $n=-20,-19,-18,-17,-16$ by $d=5$. We want to get the quotient $-4$. First, we go $-n=20,19,18,17,16$. Then we add $d-1$, which is $4$, to get $-n+d-1=24,23,22,21,20$. Now when we do integer division by $d=5$, we get $(-n+d-1)/d=(-n-1)/d+1=4$. Finally, we negate this to get $-((-n-1)/d)-1=-4$, which is what we wanted.